# Replace a subview in UICollectionView, instead of changing subview properties

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to implement a subclass of UICollectionViewCell.

I'm getting an array of custom views, let's call it `views` passed from one object to another, also with an array called `views`. They are of type `CustomView`.

The UICollectionViewCell subclass has one property called `view` of type `CustomView`.

In `CellForItemAt...`, I'm trying to set the cell's `view` property from an array of `CustomViews` like this:

```
let customView = array[indexPath.row]
cell.view = customView
```

However, when I do this, the cells don't show properly; they're empty, and just grey shapes on the screen.

But, when I explicitly set the properties of the cell's `CustomView` subview, it shows how I'd like it to.

Is there a way to do a layout pass on the cell? Or do you have to just explicitly set properties in UICollectionViewCells instead of just passing in a pre-configured view?

*The code is proprietary, so I have to be cryptic, but please let me know if I can clarify*

***Edit: Please see the comments in the accepted answer for further explanation***

Comment: Do you add the customView as a subview of cell.contentView once you set cell.view?

Comment: In the customCell's init, I add the customView as a subview, and constrain it to fill the contentView on all sides.

Comment: But you are `cell.view = customView` after cell's initialization. The cell.view in your initialization and cell.view after `cell.view = customView` are different. You have to add the new view as a subview and reset the auto layout constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be adding constraints, or else you are getting the default auto resizing mask constraints.  Call [cell.setNeedsLayout()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622601-setneedslayout) to force auto layout to recalculate before the next draw after you assing the voew.

Comment: Great call - I should have mentioned that. In the customCell's init, I add the customView as a subview, and constrain it to fill the contentView on all sides. In CellForItemAtIndexPath... I'm not adding the new customView as a subview or adding constraints. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Yes that is the issue.  You need to actually add it as a subview of the contentView.  You can keep your code as is and add a didSet remove the oldValue from its superview and add the newValue as a subview and add the constraints.